# How many parts are in a Boeing 767?

Tags: boeing-767

I've been Googling how many parts are in what air planes, but I didn't get a result on how many parts are in a Boeing 767.

Anyone got any ideas or know the answer?

Answer (score 4):

According to Boeing (on the "*interesting facts*" page on the (former) tour website for their [Everett facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Everett_Factory)) their 767 aircraft contain...

> ***...3.1 million parts** in a 767 provided by more than 800 international suppliers.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Boeing 767 Facts - **Boeing.com**](https://web.archive.org/web/20010716094702/http://www.boeing.com:80/commercial/767family/facts.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: **Now** I get what you mean. Thanks!